# How to extract time from datetime field and modify only time to 9:00 PM using groovy?

Tags: groovy, jira

I am trying to copy values across 2 datetime fields. While copying I want to set the time to 9:00 PM and pass the date value as it is.

Can anyone help on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you want to set the time component of a `java.util.Date` to 9PM, this should do it

```
Date date = new Date()
date.clearTime()
date.set((Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY): 21)
```

However, this modifies the source `Date` object in-place. To avoid this, use the following instead:

```
Date date = new Date()    
Date dateAt9PM = new Date(date.getTime()).clearTime()
dateAt9PM.set((Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY): 21)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use some groovy magic (C)

```
Date orig = new Date() + 10
Datew newDate = orig.updated( hourOfDay:19, minute:42, second:33 )
```

gives

> Sat Mar 23 19:42:33 UTC 2019